# How to handle error during python object creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

I am attempting to write a class to help me output mixed fractions.

This code works fine for my purpose

```
class mixed_fraction():
    from fractions import Fraction
    '''Returns mixed fractions in tuple format
    (whole_part, numerator, denominator)
    '''
    def __init__(self, numerator = 0, denominator = 1):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
    def mixed(self):
        if self.denominator == 0:
            return 'Denominator cannot be Zero'
        quotient = int(self.numerator/self.denominator)
        remain = self.numerator - (self.denominator * quotient)
        frac = Fraction(remain, self.denominator)
        return (quotient, frac.numerator, frac.denominator)
```

Sample inputs

```
print(mixed_fraction(3, 2).mixed())
print(mixed_fraction(1, 5).mixed())
print(mixed_fraction(1, 0).mixed())
print(mixed_fraction().mixed())
print(mixed_fraction(7, 2).mixed())
print(mixed_fraction(769, 17).mixed())
print(mixed_fraction(384, 256).mixed())
```

Outputs

```
(1, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 5)
Denominator cannot be Zero
(0, 0, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(45, 4, 17)
(1, 1, 2)
```

But I want to be able to call out the zero error at the creation of the object because it makes no sense to create a fraction with a zero divisor in the first place. So I need help on catching that error on time.

```
class mixed_fraction():
    from fractions import Fraction
    '''Returns mixed fractions in tuple format
    (whole_part, numerator, denominator)
    '''
    def __init__(self, numerator = 0, denominator = 1):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        if denominator == 0:
            return 'Denominator cannot be Zero'
    def mixed(self):
        quotient = int(self.numerator/self.denominator)
        remain = self.numerator - (self.denominator * quotient)
        frac = Fraction(remain, self.denominator)
        return (quotient, frac.numerator, frac.denominator)
```

The problem is that `__init__` must return `None`. So I am at a loss at how to go about fixing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to generate an error in Python, you don't return a value: you raise an error.

In this case, the most appropriate would be a ZeroDivisionError:

```
def __init__(self, numerator = 0, denominator = 1):
    self.numerator = numerator
    self.denominator = denominator
    if denominator == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError('Denominator cannot be Zero!')
```

ZeroDivisionError is itself an specialization of "ArithmeticError" - but you could further custmize the error for your purposes by sub-classing it:

```
class ZeroDenominatorError(ZeroDivisionError): 
    pass
```

The main advantage of it is that the program flow can fall through layers 
of code that don't handle the error properly with a `try`...`except` block - up to the place where you catch it - otherwise you have to put an `if` statement in all places you instantiate your class to check for the type of return value.

So - that is the *correct* way to handle it. Now, depending on design, it may be desirable to have the instantiation of a class to fail and return another value ("None" would be better than an error message - to have an error, just raise an exception). In that case, you should write the  `__new__` method instead of `__init__`. Unlike `__init__`, it has to return the newly created instance. (And it also has to *create* that new instance by properly calling the  `__new__` method of the superclass):

```
from fractions import Fraction

class MixedFraction(Fraction):
    def __new__(cls, numerator=0, denominator=1):
        if not denominator:
            return None
        instance = super().__new__(cls, numerator, denominator)
        return instance
    def mixed(self):
        quotient = self.numerator // self.denominator
        remain = self.numerator - (self.denominator * quotient)
        return (quotient, remain, self.denominator)
```

As for Hilliad's suggestion in his answer, this inherits from "Fraction"  directly - meaning it can be used wherever Fraction is used, but it has the extra "mixed" method. Notice that inheriting from Fraction would require you to write `__new__` instead of `__init__` if you were manipulating the numerator and denominator parameters anyway: they are set in the object at the time of instantiation, in native (`C`) code, and can't be further changed.

Comment: I'd really like to return 'None' instead of throwing an error. So should I just replace `__init__`  with  `__new__`?

Comment: no -  I will add the a full example using ` __new__`

Comment: I really appreciate the lessons. I've extended the class to return the whole numbered and the fractional parts separately if needed    
    `def whole(self):`
        `return self.mixed()[0]`
    
   `def fractional(self):`
        `return self.mixed()[1:]`

Answer (score 2):

Well if the *value* a user supplied does not make sense for your given object, *raise a `ValueError`* instead of following through with the creation:

```
def __init__(self, numerator = 0, denominator = 1):
    self.numerator = numerator
    if self.denominator == 0:
        raise ValueError("argument 'denominator' cannot be zero")
    self.denominator = denominator
```

This is the standard way cases like this should be handled.

As an aside, two small things:

- Use camel case for your class names, i.e instead of `mixed_fraction` use `MixedFraction`. (Small aside: the parentheses aren't required)
- Don't import in the class body, import it outside in the module scope.
- Consider inheriting from `Fraction` if you plan on using this in areas that expect your object to behave like a `Fraction`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How do I import from `Fraction`? Cos I did `mixed_fraction(fractions)` and it threw an error

Comment: Just move your "from fractions import Fraction" to outside the class, as suggested, and inherit from "Fraction", not form "Fractions". 
There might be some more tricks in inheriting from Fraction, though.